# Using a semivariogram to compare different images of the same site

Tags: sentinel-snap, variogram

I am writing my master degree thesis.
For my thesis I downloaded images from Copernicus and elaborated them using different methods to obtain images of FVC of some sites.
Now my tutor is asking me to compare the images obtained with different methods and find the degree of difference between them using a semivariogram.
From my understanding the semivariogram is used to calculate the autocorrelation between pixels in a georeferenced raster or between georeferenced points in a certain area.
Is there a way in which I can use it to compare rasters of images of the same site?
If there is a way, could someone share some bibliography about it?